# Where can I ask a question about bookbinding?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about the materials/glues used in binding a book for archival purposes. Which Stack Exchange site would be the most suitable for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not yet have a suitable site for your question, however there is a proposal to create one here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60509/crafts

Go follow it, vote on the defining questions, add questions to help define it, and commit to it when that times comes.

Until then do a Google search for "bookbinding forum" and you should get immediate help.

Answer (score 10):

The Crafts site proposal in [Pollyanna's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238002/398063) didn't make it, but [a new Arts and Crafts site](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) entered beta three years ago.

They do have [a [book-binding] tag](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-binding), for

> questions on the process of book binding, including preparing covers and pages, assembly, and using book binding tools.

The usual recommendation applies, namely read their [help centre](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure your question is a fit for the site. If you're still not sure, ask for help on [Arts and Crafts' Meta](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Posting this as a new answer because I'm not sure it'd be okay to edit the earlier one (as it's a pretty heavy edit, rewriting the whole answer).